# CSS background-image not loading

Tags: html, css, web, background, background-image

I am having an issue getting my background-image to load as a live website (using github pages). When i load it locally I can get it to work by entering in the full directory. However when I then move it to Github the directory changes and so it no longer works. To summarise, when I use `background-image url("images/picture.jpg");` it will not work at all. I have to type in `background-image url("c/onedrive/webroot/images/picture.jpg");` so the whole file name. However that does not work when put onto Github. Any help would be much appreciated. (:

Comment: You will need to use your Github's directory structure for the URL.

Comment: If images/picture.jpg doesn't work, then that's because it is the wrong path. We have no way of telling what the right path is.

Comment: It would help if you supply the link to your Github repo so we can see the file structure and your code.

Comment: Try to give a height to the container where the background image is applied

Answer (score 1):

As others mentioned, it seems like a file path issue. When using relative paths like `images/picture.jpg`, make sure the target image is in the correct relative location as indicated. If your `images` folder is located at the project root, your background-image url had safer/better be `/images/picture.jpg` with the `/` at the beginning to denote the project root.

**Update**

Looking at your code on the repo, I fixed it by updating the relative path — `background-image: url("../images/abstract.jpg");`

Your folder structure looks like...

```
/
|
├── css/
├── images/
├── js/ 
├── objects/
└── video/
```

Since your stylesheet in `css` folder is pointing to a file in `images` folder, you'd need to use a correct relative path.

[image: Made it work]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've tried this previously with no luck. The only way it would work is if I put the full path. However when transferred to GitHub the full path directory changes and so the background-image won't load again.

Comment: If you’re hosting your files at GitHub pages, could you share the link to your repo so we could assess?

Comment: This is the repo https://github.com/Joeet33/JETPortfolio.git. The live website is https://joeet33.github.io/JETPortfolio/

Comment: I made it work by changing the line 10 of your `index.css` to 
`background-image: url("../images/abstract.jpg");` 
That is, I made it to point go one directory level up, and find `images` folder. This works on my computer without any other changes.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem before. If you're background-image doesn't work check if your path is correct you could also right click the image in the file browser open Properties 
--> Security and copy the path from there. If this doesn't work copy the image address directly from the browser and paste it there.

Answer (score -1):

Check your path is correct

```
body {
 background-image: url("path_of_image_from_this_page.jpg");
}
```